# Solution to execute CGI scripts

Tags: apache, cgi, httpd.conf, mod-perl

I have some CGI scripts which are used internal to the organization. Due to some standard changes, the server/system team has commented the below line from httpd.conf (apache config file) that support the CGI scripts. Because of this change, the existing CGI scripts are affected and unable to execute them on browser.

### LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so

Is there a way to overcome this situation and make the scripts work as is.

NOTE : The above commented line cannot be uncommented/enabled.

Comment: So you want to run CGI scripts, but you don't want to enable cgi scripts?

Comment: @Flexo...even I feel the same. I'm trying to find if there is any other feature in Perl that can be used to overcome this situation. I 'm allowed to make any changes to the existing scripts to make them work

Comment: Re "*I'm allowed to make any changes to the existing scripts to make them work*", It doesn't matter how many changes you make to a script if you removed the means of executing it!

Comment: @ikegami...I agree to what you are saying. I tried with mod_perl but didnot have any success. I have heard of Dancer/mojolicious web frameworks but haven't used them. Does the implementation of these frameworks into the existing scripts help in any way?

Comment: What were their reasons for doing so? It sounds like you are trying to circumvent company policy!

Comment: Why would they let you have those if they don't let you have CGI? If you can run a mod_perl-enabled server, you could just as easily run a mod_cgi-enabled server.

Comment: @ikegami..I don't have answer on the reasons for doing so...Re "Why would they let you have those if they don't let you have CGI?", so I understand that even to implement these web frameworks, the CGI support on the httpd.conf file is necessary. Correct me if im wrong here.

Comment: I suspect they can be setup as FCGI and HTTP servers.

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to be running *actual* CGI scripts in this day and age, they're a security liability. If possible, adapt these to work in the `mod_perl` environment. If that's not possible, use something like [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/lib/LWP.pm) to provide an HTTP front-end to them so you can do simple proxying to the service. Depending on how big these scripts are you may want to overhaul them to use something like [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org) to make them more standard.

Comment: @tadman, LOL! mod_perl is a far less secure than CGI!

Comment: @ikegami Am I [missing something here](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-45/product_id-10711/Apache-Mod-Perl.html)? For single-tenant applications how bad is it?

Comment: @tadman, mod_perl can do everything CGI can, plus it executes code in shared proces, plus it gives access to the whole web server, plus you have to reimplement things CGI already handles for you.

Comment: @ikegami That's a feature, not a bug. Bad code will lead to bad problems in either scenario, but at least with `mod_perl` you're not launching a Perl process *per request*. I've used it on dozens of projects and it's always performed orders of magnitude faster than `.cgi` files.

Comment: @tadman, Of course a mod_perl program can be faster than a mod_cgi program. I didn't comment on its performance. I just pointed out that the mod_perl doesn't remove security liabilities as you claimed; it adds many.

Comment: Has the situation changed since the [last time you asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45864198/cgi-scripts-to-mod-perl)?

Answer (score 3):

Ways of circumventing your company's policy, from best to worse:

- Load mod_cgi anyway.
- Load mod_fcgi, and convert your CGI script into a Fast CGI daemon. It's a lot of work, but you'll can get faster code out of it!
- Load your own module that does exactly the same thing as mod_cgi. mod_cgi is open source, so it should be easy to just rename it.
- Load mod_fcgi, and write a Fast CGI daemon that executes your script.
- Install a second apache web server with mod_cgi enabled. Link to it directly or use mod_proxy on the original server.
- Write your own web server. Link to it directly or use mod_proxy on the original server.

Comment: @tadman, I haven't looked, but I've never heard of a serious web server written in Perl. When you need more performance than CGI, one usually uses FCGI.

Comment: FastCGI sounds like a better option than what you have here. The HTTP server doesn't have to be "serious", it just has to work. The first web server I ever used was in Perl, and it pre-dated the NCSA httpd program, so surely there's *something* current.

Comment: @tadman, Re "*The HTTP server doesn't have to be "serious", it just has to work*", No, it has to be reliable, secure, etc.

Comment: I'd call all of those things an integral part of any reasonable definition of something that works.

Comment: @tadman, By that definition, I've never heard of a working web server written in Perl.

Comment: It's astonishing that Node, which showed up on the block basically yesterday compared to Perl, has Express, and Perl has no answer for that?

Comment: @tadman, Node having Express is not a problem, so I'm not sure how Perl could have an answer to it.

Comment: What I mean is being able to pop up a script that can speak HTTP is exceptionally handy as it makes interfacing with existing software very easy.

Comment: @tadman, We were talking about working web servers. Perl can quite easily do what you mention, but it's *far* better to speak FCGI than HTTP. not only is the interface better, but you get to use a hardened web server.

Answer (score 0):

[Last time you asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45864198/cgi-scripts-to-mod-perl), you talked about using `mod_perl` instead. The standard way to run CGI program unchanged (for some value of "unchanged") under `mod_perl` is by using [ModPerl::Registry](https://metacpan.org/pod/ModPerl::Registry). Did you try that? How did it go?

Another alternative would be to convert your programs to use [PSGI](http://plackperl.org/). You could try using [Plack::App::Wrap::CGI](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::App::WrapCGI) or [CGI::Emulate::PSGI](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Emulate::PSGI). Using Plack would free you from any deployment restrictions. You could run the code under `mod-perl` or even as a separate service behind a proxy server.

But I can't help marvelling at how ridiculous this whole situation is. Your company has CGI programs that it (presumably) relies on to run part of its business. And they've just decided to turn off support for them. You need to find out why this decision has been made and try to buy some time in order to convert to an alternative technology.